# Design .desktop File to Launch the Default Terminal Emulator with Arguments

Tags: xfce, cinnamon, .desktop, xdg, xdg-open

I'd like to be able to open text and source code files in neovim (or any other terminal-based text editor) when an XDG-compatible GUI application asks with which application to open that file. For now, I'd be targetting xfce and cinnamon as DE/session provider.

For that, I'd write a neovim-in-default-terminal-emulator.desktop file, and start the configured default terminal emulator with the appropriate editor command.

What do I need to do to launch the DE-configured default terminal emulator from a application .desktop file with arguments of my choosing?

- It doesn't seem `update-alternatives` on modern non-debian systems (fedora38, and others) provides `x-terminal-emulator` (anymore?)
- `gsettings`-based aproaches: not my go-to, since DE-dependent, which technically is a no-go for a .desktop file which is supposed to be DE-agnostic
- I was first hoping for `default-url-scheme-handler` and then DEs registering their preferred terminal emulator for some `console://` or similar URL, but `xdg-settings get default-url-scheme-handler` is all `xdg-settings: default-url-scheme-handler not implemented for xfce` on me (does that mean I can't open, say, skype:// URLs from a browser when operating under XFCE?!)
- :-(